# C# Split string based on string and get split values and separated by values

Tags: c#, split

I have string like **(C1&&C2)**
I need to split this by using **(,&&,)** and output should be an array like..

```
(
C1
&&
C2
)
```

... tried string.split and regex.split but didn't get the expected output.

Comment: I'm not understanding your request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Regex:

```
string input = "(C1&&C2)";
List<string> output = new List<string>();
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(input,@"(\w+|\W+)"))
{
    output.Add(m.Value);
}
```

Or even simple:

```
string input = "(C1&&C2)";
string[] output = Regex.Split(input,@"\b");
```

Comment: this works like a charm... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern: `^(\()([A-Z0-9]*)(&&)([A-Z0-9]*)(\))`

It returns a set of captured groups ;)

Explanation:

`^(\()` - captures literal `(`

`([A-Z0-9]*)` - captures any character from range with any nyumber of repetitions...

`(&&)` - captures literal `&&`

`(\))` - captures literal `)`